# WiX WSLT transform to remove an attribute from a .wsx file

Tags: xslt, wix, transform

Another transform noob question: I am trying to come up with a transform that will remove an attribute from a Heated .wxs file.

Heat is generating the Class Attribute 'RelativePath="yes" which is throwing an error in the compiler.  The attribute isn't necessary in our case.  And just changing it to "no" does not get rid of the error.  What I would like to do is run a transform to remove the attribute.

The current output file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="SystemFolder">
            <Component Id="todgub7.dll" Guid="{4DEBD59A-D93A-43CC-AD8A-2198E1C308F7}" Permanent="yes">
                <File Id="todgub7.dll" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.OC2.WinSys32)\todgub7.dll">
                    <Class Id="{359AA0C1-DDF8-49DB-83FF-6184706A9106}" Context="InprocServer32" Description="ComponentOneUnboundDataSource" RelativePath="yes" ThreadingModel="apartment">
                        <ProgId Id="ComponentOneUnboundDataSource" Description="ComponentOne OLE DB Data Source for Unbound Mode" />
                    </Class>
                </File>
                <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{359AA0C1-DDF8-49db-83FF-6184706A9106}\RefCount" Value="1" Type="string" Action="write" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I am hoping to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="SystemFolder">
            <Component Id="todgub7.dll" Guid="{4DEBD59A-D93A-43CC-AD8A-2198E1C308F7}" Permanent="yes">
                <File Id="todgub7.dll" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.OC2.WinSys32)\todgub7.dll">
                    <Class Id="{359AA0C1-DDF8-49DB-83FF-6184706A9106}" Context="InprocServer32" Description="ComponentOneUnboundDataSource" ThreadingModel="apartment">
                        <ProgId Id="ComponentOneUnboundDataSource" Description="ComponentOne OLE DB Data Source for Unbound Mode" />
                    </Class>
                </File>
                <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{359AA0C1-DDF8-49db-83FF-6184706A9106}\RefCount" Value="1" Type="string" Action="write" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Here's an added piece to the puzzle I'm already running a transform to add the addtribute Pemanent="yes" to the Component.

Here is the transform I'm currently running (graciously provided from this forum):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
  xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="wix:Component">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:attribute name="Permanent">
        <xsl:text>yes</xsl:text>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this template to your stylesheet:

```
 <xsl:template match="@RelativePath"></xsl:template>
```

Since it's more specific, it will take precendence over the other template that copies attributes not named `RelativePath`.